# JBoss JNDI Naming Binding from JBoss 5 to Wildfly 21

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I am migrating from Jboss 5 to Wildfly 21.

I have some jndi binding name declared like this in Jboss 5 :

banana-service.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server>
    <mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr" name="jboss.apps:name=myapp">   
        <attribute name="BindingsConfig" serialDataType="jbxb">    
            <jndi:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0" xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd"> 
                <jndi:binding name="banana/properties/myFile"><jndi:value>C:/JBoss/jboss-5.1.0/conf/myFile.properties</jndi:value></jndi:binding>   
            </jndi:bindings>    
        </attribute>    
    </mbean>    
</server>
```

In java :

```
final Context context = new InitialContext();
file = context.lookup("banana/properties/myFile").toString();
```

So i tried to migrate it to Wildfly by multiples ways but i get the following error :

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: banana/properties/myFile-- service jboss.naming.context.java.banana.properties.myFile

standalone.xml:

1rst try :

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">            
    <bindings>
        <simple name="banana/properties/myFile" value="C:/JBoss/jboss-5.1.0/conf/myFile.properties"/>
    </bindings>
    <remote-naming/>
</subsystem>
```

2nd try :

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">          
    <lookup name="banana/properties/myFile" lookup="C:/JBoss/jboss-5.1.0/conf/myFile.properties" />
    <remote-naming/>
</subsystem>
```

But i still get the error and can't find any help on google.

How can i declare this in Wildfly 21 ?

Answer (score 0):

What about executing the following command:

```
/subsystem=naming/binding=java\:\/banana\/properties\/myFile:add(binding-type=simple, value="My File")
```